# Disable line numbering of specific lines

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, line-numbering, keywords

Is there way how to turn off numbering of lines for specific line in `algorithm2e`? I need bold `:` after keyword. So I tried redefine these macros:

```
\renewcommand{\KwIn}[1]{\textbf{Input:} #1}
\renewcommand{\KwOut}[1]{\textbf{Output:} #1}
```

But after try of this:

```
\begin{algorithm}[h]  

\SetAlgoNoLine
\DontPrintSemicolon
\LinesNumbered

\KwIn{$(X_{t-1}, u_t, z_t)$}\\
\KwOut{$X_t$}
...
...
...
\end{algorithm}
```

[image: algorithm]

So I need turn off line numbering of 2 first lines (keyword lines). Or specify new keyword which will have bold `:` after keyword name. This `\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}` is generating only normal `:` after `Input` name (**Input**: (X...)). I was searching in documentation how adjust style of input/output keywords but nothing about ending `:` found. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility redefining `\SetKwInOut`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\SetKwInOut}[2]{%
  \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo:}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname InOutSizeDefined\endcsname\relax% if first time used
    \newcommand\InOutSizeDefined{}%
    \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo\textbf{:}~}\setlength{\inoutindent}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
  \else% else keep the larger dimension
    \ifdim\wd\algocf@inoutbox>\inoutsize%
    \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo\textbf{:}~}\setlength{\inoutindent}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \fi%
  \fi% the dimension of the box is now defined.
  \algocf@newcommand{#1}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@inoutnumbered}}{\relax}{\everypar={\relax}}%
%     {\let\\\algocf@newinout\hangindent=\wd\algocf@inoutbox\hangafter=1\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo\hfill:}~##1\par}%
    {\let\\\algocf@newinout\hangindent=\inoutindent\hangafter=1\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo\textbf{:}~##1\par}%
    \algocf@linesnumbered% reset the numbering of the lines
  }}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
\Output{A partition of the bitmap}
\BlankLine
\emph{special treatment of the first line}\;
\For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{
\emph{special treatment of the first element of line $i$}\;
}
\caption{disjoint decomposition}\label{algo_disjdecomp}
\end{algorithm}\DecMargin{1em}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting error while compiling: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \inoutindent l.177 \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}`. And could you also give me possibility with `KwIn` and `KwOut`? Because I don't need same vertical align of `:`. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: @PetrPřikryl I updated my answer to suppress vertical alignment. Regarding the error message, please update your packages. My code will work with version 5.0 (january 06 2013) of `algorithm2e`.