# Algorithm2e - Disabling line numbers for specific lines

Tags: algorithm2e, line-numbering

The Algorithm2e package has specific options for disabling/hiding line numbering for the whole document or algorithm, and then enabling/showing them for specific lines. I want to do the inverse. I mean, enabling line numbering for the whole document, and then disabling them for specific lines. (A [question with similar topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104553/1347) was already asked, but it aims at a different target.)

To clarify more, I needed manual line breaks with proper indentations. So, I found the [excellent answer of @Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37208/1347) here. The problem, though, is that the manually created lines get numbering, which is undesirable in my case. Here's an example, taken directly from Werner's answer, with line numbers enabled:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\relax}}% Drop semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\dosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\algocf@endline}}% Reinstate semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\pushline}{\Indp}% Indent
\newcommand{\popline}{\Indm\dosemic}% Undent
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      \nosemic this is a very long statement that has to be\;
        \pushline\dosemic wrapped over two lines\;
      \popline current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrapped lines with numbering]

As you can see, line #7 is the wrapped line, but it gets numbered. What I want is that this line does not get any number, and the next line (line #8) gets the number 7.

Comment: similar: [Unnumbered lines in algorithm](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107459/579) (uses `algorithm` package, not `algorithm2e`)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you load [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) with `linesnumbered`, it executes `\nl` at every paragraph break (taken from [`algorithm2e.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty)):

```
%
% line numbering
%
\newcommand{\LinesNumbered}{%
  \setboolean{algocf@linesnumbered}{true}%
  \renewcommand{\algocf@linesnumbered}{\everypar={\nl}}}%
```

So, `\nl` is the thing we are interested in adjusting.

You can remove the line number for a single line using the following `\nonl` command:

```
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
```

Here's a minimal example showing the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\relax}}% Drop semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\dosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\algocf@endline}}% Reinstate semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\pushline}{\Indp}% Indent
\newcommand{\popline}{\Indm\dosemic}% Undent
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      \nosemic this is a very long statement that has to be\;
        \pushline\dosemic\nonl wrapped over two lines\;
      \popline current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

`\nonl` redefines `\nl` for one usage. That usage is just to redefine itself to use the original form (a similar-style trick is used in [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764)).

Comment: Brilliant, I wish I could up vote your answer twice!

Comment: is it possible to remove the numberings at 'else' and 'ends' ?
if yes kindly tell me how, thanks