# algorithm2e - `\small` interferes with `\nonl` (line number removal)

Tags: algorithm2e, line-numbering

I use a custom command [\nonl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153906/202724), which removes the line number for a certain line.

- When I simply use `\nonl`, it works.
- When I use `{\small \nonl ...}`, it works.
- When I use `\nonl {\small ...}`, it also removes the line number for the next line.

What's the reason? I kind of expected the opposite (that `{\small \nonl ...}` won't work).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\let\oldnl\nl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    Line \\
    \nonl Nonl here \\
    Line \\
    {\small \nonl Nonl inside small here} \\
    Line \textbf{where number didn't disappear} \\
    \nonl {\small Nonl outside small here} \\
    Line \textbf{where number disappeared} \\
    Line \\
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. `\small` is actually unrelated: the braced group is causing the problem.