# Change line number only after \; in algorithm2e

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, algorithm2e

How can I have the regular behaviour of some paragraphs placed together, without changing line number in the algorithm after one paragraph ends?

I want that line number changes only after a `\;` appears and having the paragraphs indented as usual.

The contents of `\If`, `\For`, `\While`, must follow the same rule: only numerate a line after `\;`.

So, next MWE would have six numbered lines (assuming that lines of the start and end of block are numbered): two lines for the start and end of `\While` block, two lines for its contents and two lines for the next paragraphs.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\While{$i < n$}{
First line numbered...

First line continues in new paragraph...
first line ends.\;

Second line.\;
}

First line numbered...

First line continues in new paragraph...
first line ends.\;

Second line starts...

Second line continues in new paragraph...
second line ends.\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the content inside its own block (like a fixed-width `\parbox` that is *anchored* at the `[t]`op):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  First line numbered\ldots

  First line continues in new paragraph\ldots
  first line ends.\;

  Second line starts\ldots

  Second line continues in new paragraph\ldots
  second line ends.\;
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\algowidth-2\algomargin}{First line numbered\ldots

  First line continues in new paragraph\ldots
  first line ends.}\;
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\algowidth-2\algomargin}{Second line starts\ldots

  Second line continues in new paragraph\ldots
  second line ends.}\;
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

---

Another, automated way of handling this is to change `\nl` so that it only prints a `n`umbered `l`ine once and then deactivates itself. Additionally, let `\;` temporarily reactivate `\nl` before shutting it down again. The redefinition of these macros are done using a hook into the `\begin` part of the `algorithm` `env`ironment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/algorithm/begin}{%
  % At the start of algorithm, make \nl only print something once
  \let\oldnl\nl
  \def\nl{\oldnl\let\nl\relax}
  \let\old@endalgoln\@endalgoln
  % Update \; (or \@endalgoln) to do the same thing
  \renewcommand{\@endalgoln}{%
    \def\nl{\oldnl\let\nl\relax}%
    \old@endalgoln
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  First line numbered\ldots

  First line continues in new paragraph\ldots
  first line ends.\;

  Second line starts\ldots

  Second line continues in new paragraph\ldots
  second line ends.\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

<sub>I'm not sure whether this may break other components of the algorithm structure.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I'd prefer something that leaves unchanged the MWE (like redefine `\;` and `\nl` commands or something else).

Comment: @AlbertoLópez: You're going to have to intervene in the code somehow if you're expecting the code to deliver something other than the default. Just saying...

Comment: @AlbertoLópez: You can also consider this as an option (maybe less invasive): [Algorithm2e - Disabling line numbers for specific lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153646/5764)

Comment: Yes, that is my last option, but I'm almost sure that it can be done redefining `\;` and `\nl` (which I already did but without success) or something similar. It would be more elegant solution, avoiding putting a command at the beginning of every par.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez: Automation suggests you have to do this hundreds of times, making manual intervention error-prone. Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct, saving time and energy.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez: See the updated answer that redefines `\nl` and `\;` (actually `\@endalgoln`) to achieve your goal. I'm not confident this will break other things within an `algorithm`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it, it only remains indenting like in normal text, but it's a great progress.

Comment: The `\AddToHook` command isn't been recognized, which package does it belongs?, it seems it's a kernel problem, can't be solved with other well known commands?

Comment: @AlbertoLópez: You need to update your distribution, as this has been incorporated into the LaTeX kernel since Oct 2020. As an alternative, add `\usepackage{xparse}` before `\AddToHook`.

Comment: I already added `\usepackage{xparse}` and error still appears.

Comment: I only use the redefinition of commands (content of `\AddToHook`) and it works for text paragraphs but lines inside macros like `\While`, `\For`, etc are not being correctly numbered.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez: Here's a suggestion: Provide a complete, minimal example that replicates your current setup and also provides edge cases that need to be addressed. Read this for more details on how to present an MWE: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: Done, I edited it with more detail.